# Iterate with step and apply function

Tags: loops, clojure

How can I do something like this pseudo-C++ code:

```
vector<int> vs = {...};
for (i = start; i < vs.size(); i += step) {
  vs[i] *= 10;
}
```

in Clojure? I have this code:

```
(defn step-do [start step v]
  (if (< start (count v))
    (recur (+ start step) step (assoc v start (* 10 (v start))))
    v))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println (step-do 2 3 (vec (range 1 15)))))
```

Or `for` variant:

```
(defn step-do [start step v]
  (last (for [i (range start (count v) step)]
          (assoc v i (* 10 (v i))))))
```

What is better? What is faster? Should I do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recur`-based version is perfectly fine and likely to be among the fastest possible solutions, though you might want to use transients if it's going to operate on larger vectors.

As a possible alternative I'd suggest using `reduce` to handle the looping, with the input vector passed in as the initial value of the accumulator and the reduced sequence provided by `range` with a step argument.

```
(defn step-do [start step v]
  (reduce (fn [v i]
            (assoc v i (* 10 (nth v i))))
          v
          (range start (count v) step)))
```

From the REPL:

```
(def xs (vec (range 32)))

(step-do 1 2 xs)
;= [0 10 2 30 4 50 6 70 8 90 10 110 12 130 14 150 16 170 18 190 20 210 22 230 24 250 26 270 28 290 30 310]
```

This has the benefit of clearly separating the selection of indices at which the transformation is to be applied (here handled by `range`; a more involved seq producer could be used if desired) and the transformation itself (captured by the function passed to `reduce`; a generalized `step-do` could accept a a transformation function as an argument, rather than hardwire multiply-by-10).

Additionally, it should be quite performant (and since `reduce` is quite central to Clojure's model of data handling, it's likely to keep improving in future releases). Of course here too transients could be used to speed things up.

Comment: Incidentally, it's entirely possible to use a native array in place of the vector here (hopefully with a type hint!). The reduction function would then use something like `(aset arr i (* 10 (aget arr i)))`, with the collection being reduced over still coming from `range`. I wrote the answer in terms of vectors because of the Clojure code snippets in the question, but the pattern of using `reduce` to transform something in a non-trivial but predictable loop is more broadly applicable. Also worth pointing out in this connection is the recently-introduced `reduced` for early termination.

Answer (score 1):

```
(def an-array (int-array 25000 (int 1)))
(time (amap ^ints an-array
                  idx
                  ret
                  (* (if (zero? (mod idx step)) (int 10) (int 1))
                  (aget ^ints an-array idx))))

"Elapsed time: 14.708653 msecs"
;; Note: without type hinting the performance of would not be good.
```

[amap](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/amap)

Comment: If I use this function, for some sequence with steps 2, 3, 4 and so on I will get `O(n ** 2)` performance, but my solution will run in `O(n log n)` time. Function `amap` is not what I want.

Comment: If your problem is to perform arithmetic on a native array of primitives in place this will zoom. You may want to do the experiment.